# Conditional compilation in Java

Tags: java, groovy, conditional-compilation

Is there any way I can tell the java compiler which file to compile based on some requirement? Actually I have two versions of same file named Uta.groovy(it is groovy based) but based on platform I am testing I need to use different versions.
Say I want to rename files like Uta5.groovy and Uta7.groovy and tell compiler which file to consider for compilation. Both have similar codes but with some minor changes in return type and params.

Comment: Maybe we could suggest you a different approach?  Could you edit in order to state which are the platform requirements that change per platform?  That way we may suggest you some way to integrate them into your code instead of repeating classes and conditionally compile them

Comment: Hi Jorge_B, what could be the alternate approach for this. The main problem is we can not merge the both files. So, we need to use different files mandatory.

Comment: I actually meant, for example: if I need 2 different strategies to resolve a certain problem, and I must use one of them or the other one depending on something that I maybe can identify at runtime, then maybe I can combine these 2:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern
In some way that suits me and does not make me write twice the same class, that is *always* a bad idea

Comment: Thanks, Jorge. The idea is good. We can do that, but the problem is we are sort of time for doing this where each function of the class will be merged and tested thereafter. Certainly, in the starting only the design has been screwed up , but we had to live with that .